# Add custom text to order confirmation email when a product is out of stock

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hello hope someone could help me out.

I keep selling products when they are out of stock, what i'm trying to do is: When a customer orders a product which is out of stock i would like to display a custom message in the order confirmation email for ex. You ordered a product which is out of stock, the delivery time is 5-7 days longer.

If non of the products are out of stock there shouldn't be displayed anything. just the normal email text.

Hope someone could help me out.

Greetings, Rutger

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings/notification, you'll see an email template "order confirmation".
And then, insert this:

```
{% if product.available %}
 <p>Send this message....</p>
{% else %}
<p>Send something else...</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Marina, 

Thank you for the answer. I already tried this exact solution but it does not work. I'm only getting the else output even when the product is in stock.

Comment: You're welcome.
Can you put ss here or just copy that piece of code where you were adding this?